# Show Bootstrap radio inputs as buttons, but not as a button group

Tags: bootstrap-4

Bootstrap can give `<input type="radio"`s a button look ([see here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons)) but it seems that this works properly only if they are put into a button group.

I'm going to have many of them so to have them wrapping nicely with the page, I removed their `<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">` container, but this way the look is degraded: The radio knob is shown and the buttons don't preserve their toggled look. ([see here](https://jsfiddle.net/reLheb56/))

Do you know any workaround to have the radios displayed nicely as buttons without the need of having them as a button group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the markup below will do the trick. The actual trick is to still wrap the `.btn`s with a `<div data-toggle="buttons">`, but not setting the `.btn-group` class on it. The `data-toggle="buttons"` attribute will still provide the functionality, and the visual representation will be that of individual buttons.
A [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dferenc/4o144s75/) with more radio options is available too.

```html
<div data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off"> Radio 1
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio 2
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio 3
    </label>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I opened [an issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/25067) on GitHub so the documentation will include an example for individual buttons.